# ANR doing setContentView in onCreate caused by google maps?

Tags: java, android, performance

This single line of code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

takes from 2 to 7-8 seconds to finish executing, since I added a Google Maps v2 fragment in my layout, today i received this ANR in my develper console:

```
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40022190 self=0xcec8
| sysTid=16482 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1345006400
| schedstat=( 602203379 1347412095 699 )
at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.<init>(AccessibleObject.java:~132)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.<init>(Method.java:122)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassCache.getDeclaredPublicMethods(ClassCache.java:153)
at java.lang.ClassCache.getMethodsRecursive(ClassCache.java:216)
at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethods(ClassCache.java:175)
at java.lang.ClassCache.getMethods(ClassCache.java:167)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:961)
at com.google.googlenav.capabilities.a.b((null):-1)
at maps.af.w.a((null):-1)
at maps.z.ab.a((null):-1)
at maps.z.ab.a((null):-1)
at maps.z.ag.a((null):-1)
at maps.z.ag.a((null):-1)
at maps.z.bw.a((null):-1)
at maps.z.r.onCreateView((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$Stub.onTransact(IMapFragmentDelegate.java:107)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.e$4.a((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.a((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.e.onCreateView((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView((null):-1)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:884)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at com.frakman.mapbook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:285)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Thread-13" prio=5 tid=10 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40557ef8 self=0x2249c8
| sysTid=16524 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=2247424
| schedstat=( 39337155 97991945 106 )
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4055e098> (a com.google.ads.internal.c)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
at com.google.ads.internal.c.run(SourceFile:758)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Thread-12" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40517058 self=0x21d3c0
| sysTid=16515 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=2217208
| schedstat=( 1129151 16143798 6 )
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:1881)
at android.app.ActivityThread.getProvider(ActivityThread.java:3351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:3376)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1689)
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:748)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:256)
at com.google.ads.as$a.run(SourceFile:75)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"CookieSyncManager" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4056b3e8 self=0x1e7ef0
| sysTid=16512 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1990240
| schedstat=( 1007081 42510985 9 )
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.webkit.WebSyncManager.run(WebSyncManager.java:90)
at android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.run(CookieSyncManager.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40562ec8 self=0x1bc140
| sysTid=16510 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1819256
| schedstat=( 56762704 347106931 100 )
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:119)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:117)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:685)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40513fa0 self=0x17ad48
| sysTid=16489 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1499600
| schedstat=( 2532958 55328369 10 )
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40513260 self=0x16ebd8
| sysTid=16488 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1499536
| schedstat=( 2868652 35583496 7 )
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510498 self=0x16eaa0
| sysTid=16487 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1424864
| schedstat=( 41778568 58563232 164 )
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
| group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x405103d8 self=0x15b658
| sysTid=16485 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1428136
| schedstat=( 8483884 45806889 24 )
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510330 self=0x16dfd0
| sysTid=16484 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1429376
| schedstat=( 99792479 377410890 75 )
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510278 self=0x15bc20
| sysTid=16483 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=1429632
| schedstat=( 4180908 8453369 17 )
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

could it be related to the long time setContentView takes to finish? Does anybody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Update:
this is my main.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#CCCCCC"
        >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#4099FF"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

      <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="a151544472ef24f"
                         ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

        <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#4099FF">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/checkin"
            style="@style/NewButton.ButtonCheckin"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/query"
            style="@style/NewButton.ButtonRefresh"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"

             />
    </LinearLayout>

        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/authButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layoutButtons"
             />

         </RelativeLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressCircle"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressCircle2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/bar"
            android:visibility="gone"
             />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/adView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
                style="@style/NewButton.ButtonSettings"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                 />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                style="@style/NewButton.ButtonSearch"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                 />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/infoButton"
                style="@style/NewButton.ButtonInfo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The really strange behavior is that this slow start happens only the first time you launch the application, or if it's some hours since you closed it, while if you close it with back button and even from recent apps, then it starts in a second, quickly, I really don't understand why.
PS adMob is part of the application too.

Edit: here's TraceView (original image [here](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/2491/traceview.png) )

[image]

Comment: "This single line of code... takes from 2 to 7-8 seconds to finish executing" -- without seeing `main.xml`, it will be difficult for anyone to help you. These Maps V2 samples do not take 2+ seconds to start up, let alone process `setContentView()`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2 Beyond that, use Traceview to try to peer into what is going on.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine precisely where your problem lies.

Comment: I added Traceview, looks like LayoutInflater is taking too much?

Comment: I cannot tell much from a static screenshot -- the power of Traceview is in the exploration. That being said, about half of your time is *not* from `setContentView()` and its descendants (delta between lines 0 and 1). A quarter of your time is in Maps V2 itself (line 13 and its descendants). It is difficult to tell where the rest of the time is going specifically.

Comment: ok, i'm trying, however thank you again for your help, I think I found the most time expensive task, but i can't understand really what's going on...I selected it in this screenshot, it seems it hasn't children: http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/3005/48233269.png, btw maybe half of the time is not from setcontentview but isn't it too much time anyway?

Comment: That is rather strange. I have no idea why it is taking that long, other than perhaps a very underpowered device.

Comment: It's a Galaxy Nexus. Ok, so I'll do nothing for now, thank you